# Make mirror of .onion in clearnet

Tags: onion-services

I have a domain and website in .onion now I want to make site's mirror in clearnet. How should I do that?

Comment: This question isn't clear or is too broad. Can you be more specific about what you need and what platform you're working with? What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: This is not really a Tor question. You'd want to work on the definition of your virtual hosts and that depends on which type of web server you're using. For example in Apache have a look at the ServerAlias directive.

Comment: I've got ngnix and tor with .onion site. Now I want to make a mirror of .onion site in clearnet.

Comment: Do you want to "mirror" your own site or a foreign site?

Comment: My own but the same time I don't want compromise my .onion server. Make the mirror located in different server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you must make **JUST** another name-based alias in your web server config. Yes, that's all of it! Because Tor is *just* a stunnel-like reverse port mapper. So all the rest is managed on your web server and web site side. I do recommend to arise an environment variable like `HTTPS` - let's say `DARKNET` - so your web site CMS will be omitting any privacy tracking related stuff from the resulting HTML code - like Google Analytics, e.t.c. You **don't** need to reconfigure your Tor at all! But there is a security issue ;)

To do it properly secure - put your web server into the fully isolated VM or container, then route traffic from Tor and from Clearnet reverse proxy into it. Why's that? To mitigate an exploitation vector for de-anonymizing darknet users: if an enemy will be able to launch a *direct* request from your web server when your client is visiting you through the darknet(not just Tor - any of them, like I2P, e.t.c...) - a data leak vector is established. That's why you do need this kind of insulation. But no reconfiguration is needed further ;)

Feel free to drop me a line if you need further clarification or help in that question!